# Aem fulltext Search apostrophe s ('s) is not working

Tags: java, aem

I have write query on AEM Query builder

Working code

```
fulltext=*Australia*
path=/content/mysite/mypages
type=cq:Page
```

But not working with

```
fulltext=*Australia's*
path=/content/mysite/mypages
type=cq:Page
```

Please help me get search result if text contain special character or apostrophe s ('s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query shows that you are using a cq:Page type where that means you are searching a page names. if it is true, suggest not to use any special character in the url for page names.

to reproduce your issue i have changed the page name as below.

```
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar to /content/geometrixx/en/toolbar's
```

and the blow code snippet shows the results for page

```
fulltext=*toolbar"'"s*
path=/content/geometrixx/en
type=cq:Page
```

[image]